How can i make it so when i click on the image it operates like the button
I am making a website about trains and want to optimize it for phones. I want to make it so when i click on the button shown in the html code it shows the elements inside the div with a class mobile-phone-nav-bar. I got the button working but when i added image i saw that if i click on it it doesn't work. How can i make it so when i click on the image it operates like the button and shows the elements inside the div.


function Menu() {
    document.getElementById("phone-nav-bar").classList.toggle("show-nav-bar");
  }

  // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.menu-button')) {
      var navBar = document.getElementById("phone-nav-bar");
      if (navBar.classList.contains('show-nav-bar')) {
        navBar.classList.remove('show-nav-bar');
      }
    }
  }
.mobile-phone-nav-bar{
    display:none;
}
.show-nav-bar{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
<div class="menu-toggle">

            <button class="menu-button" onclick="Menu()"><img src="assets/images/menu.png"></button>

            <div class="mobile-phone-nav-bar" id="phone-nav-bar">

                <a class="nav-button" href="index.html">Начало</a>
                
                <div class="train-dropdown">
                    
                    <button onclick="TrainDropdown()" class="dropdown-button">Влакове</button>
                    
                    <div id="trains" class="train-elements">
                    
                        <a id="first-element" href="#">Link 1</a>
                        
                        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    
                        <a id="last-element" href="#">Link 3</a>
                    
                    </div>

                </div> 
                
                <a class="nav-button" href="#contacts">Контакти</a>
                <a class="nav-button" href="#aboutme">Повече за мен</a>
            
            </div>

        </div>




"It doesn't work" isn't particularly helpful. What's the expected behavior, specifically? What steps have you taken to debug it?

I can't debug it when i don't know how it works. I have no knowledge in JS. I just want someone to show me where have i made a mistake because the elements won't show up and how to fix it.

@bavanta The only I could find was clicking the image (or here the image-missing icon)within the button it does not trigger the function. But if i press the button itself it works normally. Is that what you meant by not working? If so please edit the post accordingly.

if (!event.target.matches('.menu-button')) { only matches the button, not the image, so if you click on the image it "doesn't work" but if you click on the button outside the image, it "works" fine.

"I have a time limit" - quickest solution is to remove the image and use some text.

Oh sorry about that. I didnt know what was my mistake and thought its something in the JS code. I will edit it accordingly

When Menu() fires, so does your anonymous window.onclick function.

... (to continue above comment) so the menu is shown via Menu() but then immediately hidden by window.onclick

... and tweaked it to work for me but it just doesn't work <-- Those two statements are contradictory.

The issue might be related to how the onclick event is used on the window. You need to prevent window.onclick from closing the menu when you click the .menu-button or any element inside the dropdown. Also, make sure the dropdown is managed correctly.


        function Menu() {
            const navBar = document.getElementById("phone-nav-bar");
            navBar.classList.toggle("show-nav-bar");
        }

        function TrainDropdown() {
            const trainElements = document.getElementById("trains");
            if (trainElements.style.display === "none") {
                trainElements.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                trainElements.style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        window.onclick = function (event) {
            const menuButton = document.querySelector('.menu-button');
            const navBar = document.getElementById("phone-nav-bar");

            if (!menuButton.contains(event.target) && !navBar.contains(event.target)) {
                navBar.classList.remove("show-nav-bar");
            }
        }
.mobile-phone-nav-bar {
    display: none;
}

.show-nav-bar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
 <div class="menu-toggle">
        <button class="menu-button" onclick="Menu()">
            <img src="assets/images/menu.png">
        </button>
        <div class="mobile-phone-nav-bar" id="phone-nav-bar">
            <a class="nav-button" href="index.html">Начало</a>
            <div class="train-dropdown">
                <button onclick="TrainDropdown()" class="dropdown-button">Влакове</button>
                <div id="trains" class="train-elements" style="display:none;">
                    <a id="first-element" href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a id="last-element" href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="nav-button" href="#contacts">Контакти</a>
            <a class="nav-button" href="#aboutme">Повече за мен</a>
        </div>
    </div>



